# Database connection, table related control and configuration in ASP.net

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, asp.net-mvc-4, visual-studio-2012

While working with the ASP.net MVC project in Visual studio, where is the place to control/mention the database connections and the related tables need to be used in the project by the SQL?. Is it under the View or Model or Controller folder code or Data connections in the Server explorer?.

Do we need to write this connection details in code or the configuration in the Data Connection enough?.

Comment: do you mean data access layer?

Comment: For this asp.net project where and how to connect with the required databases and tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Configuration is web.config is enough for database connections. You can use it from there is DB applications. You should write connection details in code and use connection string from web.config `Configuration --> ConnectionStrings` section.

If you want to keep details of names of tables or procedures used in the application, you can create a constants.cs file for that and store the details as const variables in SQLInfo class.

```
public class SQLInfo{
   public const string proc1_name = "";
   //........and so on.
}
```

Comment: Thanks.Then what is the usefulness of the Data Connections under the Server Explorer(In Visual Studio). For what purpose do we need to use that?

Comment: Basically, to open SQL Server management studio stuff in Server Explorer so that you do not need to open separate instance of SQL Server management studio for stuff like Add new table, Stored procedure, or modify or create table design from here. You can get the script directly as you design a table. This allows to provide for most of the stuff that developers generally do while working with SQL. It's mostly for those who are not very adept at working with SQL or SSMS and still develop using database.

Comment: Hi Amit, Clear now. Then people said about of using ADO.net to connect with the database and database queries. Don't we need to use this ADO.net in asp.net MVC?. Is it the web.config configuration enough to do database queries?.

Comment: ADO.net is part of .net framework available as DLLs of framework. In your data access layer, which is a bunch of class files (.cs), you can write code to connect to database using namespaces provided by ADO.net easily, using the connection string from web.config. It is always better to store connection string at one place (web.config) so that changing it does not cause any unexpected issues while deploying website to different machines (production, QA) which will use different databases. And on every environment, you will have its own database connection string.

Comment: Thanks.Can we configure multiple database connections (say SQL server and Oracle database in different locations, but are used in one asp.net project) in the web.config file? Can we use this web.config connection while we work with LINQ?

Comment: Yes. Create connection strings with different names. Use your connection string at runtime based on the database type you are trying to connect since your Data access layer may require to be slightly different for working SQL server or Oracle.

Comment: Hi Amit, I can see cs extension files under Controllers folder and Model folder. Where do we need to create this data access layer and ADO.net code?. Under Controllers or Model folder?

Comment: Create a new folder with name DAL or DataAccess. Create these files there.

Comment: Last question. Are there any particular place to get the Connection String for different databases from asp.net?. I found SQL express and SQL Server. But for Oracle or other MySQL databases, Informix..... from asp.net.

Comment: No doubt you cleared a lot in my mind. Have a great day and god bless you.